# react to SIGTERM with yesod application

Tags: haskell, heroku, yesod

When I start up my yesod application, I create a connection to a rabbitmq server that I store in the `App` datatype to access during requests. When I deploy a new version of the app or restart my server, I want to gracefully close this connection. Something along the lines of:

```
import System.Posix.Signals(sigTERM, installHandler, Handler(..))
appMain :: IO ()
appMain = do
    settings <- loadAppSettingsArgs [configSettingsYmlValue] useEnv
    foundation <- makeFoundation settings
    app <- makeApplication foundation

    --install shutdown handler here
    installHandler sigTERM (Catch (closeConnection (rabbitmqConn app))) Nothing
    runSettings (warpSettings foundation) app
```

however if i do this the process won't exit at all(and heroku will send a SIGKILL eventually. so I could do

```
import System.Posix.Signals(sigTERM, installHandler, Handler(..))
import System.Exit(exitSuccess)
appMain :: IO ()
appMain = do
    settings <- loadAppSettingsArgs [configSettingsYmlValue] useEnv
    foundation <- makeFoundation settings
    app <- makeApplication foundation

    --install shutdown handler here, this time exit the process after we close the connection

    installHandler sigTERM (Catch ((closeConnection $ rabbitmqConn conn) >> exitSuccess)) Nothing
    runSettings (warpSettings foundation) app
```

However I'm worried that I might exit the application and prevent other handlers from running if I do this in the wrong place(and prevent gracefull shutdown of something else). I'm wondering if there is a place in my yesod app that I should be adding this type of code that will fit in with the rest of the framework.

Comment: Are you suggesting there might already be a `SIGTERM` handler installed, and you're worried about overwriting existing behavior? I wasn't sure what you meant by "an ad-hoc addition of sigTERM handler and could prevent my app from gracefully shutting down other things"

Comment: @MaxGabriel Yes I'm worried I would be short circuiting existing handlers if I don't do this in the right place